# Searching for iPhone SDK for iPhone OS 2.2.1 (Build 9m2621a)

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, osx-leopard, iphone-sdk-2.2.1

I am searching the last SDK for the iPhone OS 2.2.1 (last in the 2.x series) for Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard:
**"iPhone SDK for iPhone OS 2.2.1 (Build 9m26211) - Final"**

Exact Data of the searched SDK:

- type: DMG
- file name: **"iphone_sdk_for_iphone_os_2.2.19m2621afinal.dmg"**
- md5-checksum: "9d0a818f41be507537495920cd0ef9bc"
- file size: 1.75 GB
- original (non-working) link: [original link to SDK (not working
  anymore)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_for_iphone_os_2.2.1__9m2621a__final/iphone_sdk_for_iphone_os_2.2.19m2621afinal.dmg)

Unfortunately, Apple has **deleted** most of the old developer stuff lately, so I **cannot** download the SDK anymore !

But I need it **urgently** for a project.
If you have a backup of the DMG file, could you please provide me a copy of this ?
Send me an e-mail. (my address is: "Kitchen2010 (AT) web DOT de")

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Apple's Xcode page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and click on the link that's next to "Looking for additional developer tools? View downloads", you'll be able to get to older copies of Xcode that are compatible with older versions of MacOS & iOS.

You do need to be a member of Apple's Developer Program to authenticate to get in there, though.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Dautermann:
Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, the oldest Xcode release with iOS/iPhone OS SDK included and still available for download is "**Xcode 3.2.3 with iOS SDK 4.0.1**" for Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard on this site. All **earlier** Xcode releases are for **Mac OS X development only**.

Apple used to distribute the iOS/iPhone OS SDKs with a suitable Xcode as a **seperated download**. They started to combine the Xcode releases later with the 3.2.x releases.

I still hope that someone has made a backup of the **early iPhone OS SDKs** and can provide me a copy.